# How to store value in dropdown using string array? Call in selenium web driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am creating script but did not get perfect call. please help me how to create script dropdown value store in array. I an unable to call in selenium web drive.

Dropdown menu scrrenshot: http://prntscr.com/100j0km
Dropdown menu list: http://prntscr.com/100j1og

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
    WebElement facultyId = driver.findElement(By.id("faculty_id"));
    facultyId.click(); // to make the options to appear
    Thread.sleep(500); // if not using implicit wait
    List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> texts = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<WebElement> options = facultyId.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
    for (WebElement option: options) {
        values.add(option.getAttribute("value"));
        texts.add(option.getText());
    }
            
    String[] collectedValues = (String[]) values.toArray();
    String[] collectedTexts = (String[]) texts.toArray();
```

Comment: I am trying to using script mention in above but it is not dropdown the value clickable and get the value.

http://prntscr.com/100tm34

Comment: I've edited my answer. Please always post your code including console output.

Comment: Still Is not working.

Html Code= https://prnt.sc/103kh9e
Script code =https://prnt.sc/103kjb2
Console Output = https://prnt.sc/103kk2g

Answer (score 0):

Check Below Answer I have used this script

```
// options to appear
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"s2id_autogen3\"]")).click(); // options to appear
       Thread.sleep(6000);
       driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"s2id_autogen3\"]")).sendKeys("Office Department"); //pass the sendkeys
       Thread.sleep(6000);
       
       //Use the Using explicit wait
       WebDriverWait Faculties = new WebDriverWait(driver, 120);
       WebElement Departments =Faculties.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("*//Put the xpath for finding keyword"))); //Put the xpath for finding keyword  
       Departments.click(); //Click on finding keyword
```